# Excluding collections from view layer using script

Tags: python

Hello Im working on really big project and I need to exclude all collections from layerand reverse using script I tried this

```
import bpy

coll = bpy.data.collections
for c in coll:
   c.exclude = False
```

But it doesnt seem to work, any ideas where it went wrong or how to solve my problem? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use refence from view_layer.layer_collection:

```py
import bpy
   
vl_colls = bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection.children

# toggle
for coll in vl_colls:
    coll.exclude = not coll.exclude
```

## Layer collection vs Collection:

reference

- [LayerCollection(bpy_struct)](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.LayerCollection.html)
- [Collection(ID)](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Collection.html)

[image: ![](outliner.png)]

### Properties of LayerCollection(bpy_struct):

[image: ![](layercoll%20props.png)]

- Exclude: `.exclude`
- Hide in Viewport: `.hide_viewport`
- Holdout: `.holdout`
- Indirect Only: `.indirect_only`

Accessed through `bpy.context.view_layer.layer_collection.children`

### Properties of Collection(ID):

[image: ![](coll%20props.png)]

- Disable Selection: `.hide_select`
- Disable in Viewport: `.hide_viewport`
- Disable in Render: `.hide_render`

Accessed through `bpy.data.collections`

Comment: This won't work for more nested collections though.

Comment: Yep it seems there's no way to find exclude for nested collections